# Dark LookAndFeel for Swing

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel

Is there any free cool dark LookAndFeel like [Intelij Dracula](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/12/intellij-idea-12-is-available-for-download/) that work perfect on Windows and Linux?

Comment: Have you tried to Google it?

Comment: Insubstantial probably has a dark theme

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[JTattoo](http://www.jtattoo.net/index.html) might be what you are looking for. Here's a couple of screenshots:

[image]

[image]